# Angular + ui-router :: on state complete callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `$state.go(url)` to navigate in a few factories. To avoid flickering I would like to subscribe my animation to start when the new state is fully loaded. *(not just the url change)*

If there any way to add a callback within a factory that is called when the state's html is inserted and/or first `digest` cycle is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to operate `$stateChangeStart` and continue with `$viewContentLoaded` events.

Your state is as precise as many promises you added to resolve function at state configuration. So if your *full load state* depends on data readiness and page rendering finish state - you need to sure that controller will not load until you missing anything.

Only awareness of showing animation between this events is - each view placed on your current state will call separate `$viewContentLoaded`.

In case of that I was unloading animation after number of child views equals number of events happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen the event `$stateChangeSuccess` that is fired when the state transition is complete:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    // your code here
});
```

[Check the UI Router doc about states and events](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Comment: But simple state change success does not give such precise for knowing when view actually ready. That event fired only after controller is resolved and init method is done but not after view compilation success. Or I'm missing some hidden ability of success event?